# Database for R^n --> R^m function evaluation caching

Tags: database, scientific-computing

I'm trying to choose the best database for caching a n inputs, m outputs function:

- It has to persist the result of the evaluation of some (costly) R^n ---> R^m function. So there's a fixed structure: n fields for the inputs, m for the outputs, and all of them are floating points.
- The number of records can easily go in the hundreds of millions. The dataset will exceed the RAM, but will surely fit on a SSD. RAM upgrades are not an option.
- Does not need to be distributed; it will run on one machine
- There will be only **one type of query**, in which all fields of the records must be selected according to a range in *each* of the n inputs simultaneously (think of a multi-field BETWEEN sql query).
- ...but it has to have *really* good performance at that query. The volume of queries will be minimal, but the execution time must be blazing fast.
- BONUS: the data returned will be grid-interpolated. The availability of fast DB-side interpolation would be a plus.